# A function cannot be accessed when the program is running

Tags: java, methods, semaphore

I am working on homework about thread synchronization. The method reduceLoad() cannot be accessed when I call this method. All print function inside the reduceLoad() method are never called. If I can't run this method, the key will never be released.

It might be caused by Semaphore.accquire() and Semaphore.realse(). So I tried to delete all Semaphore methods that may cause the problem.

> Protion of the program result below:

As you can see the program is held after all threads print "disembarks from ferry at port "

> ..... omit some result here....
>
> Arrive at port 1 with a load of 5 vehicles
>
> Auto 4 arrives at port 0
>
> Ambulance 1 arrives at port 1
>
> Ambulance 1 boards the ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 6 boards on the ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 8 boards on the ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 0 disembarks from ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 2 disembarks from ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 1 disembarks from ferry at port 1
>
> Ambulance 0 disembarks the ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 7 boards on the ferry at port 1
>
> Auto 3 disembarks from ferry at port 1

This is where the function is called

```
      // Arrive at the next port
  port = 1 - port;

  // wait for ferry arrives
  while (fry.getPort() != port) {
    try {
      sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }

  // disembarking
  System.out.println("Auto " + id_auto + " disembarks from ferry at port " + port);
  logger.check(fry.getPort() == port, "error unloading at wrong port");
  fry.reduceLoad(); // Reduce load
  System.out.println("Auto " + id_auto + " successfully disembarks from ferry at port " + port);
```

This method reduceLoad() should release a key when the ferry is empty, this key is used to notify other threads to continue adding more cars into the ferry

```
public synchronized void reduceLoad() {

logger.check(load > 0, "error unloading an empty Ferry!");
load = load - 1;
System.out.println("removed load, now " + load);

if (load == 0) {
  unloadingDone.release();
}
```

}

Comment: Post some code?

Comment: What is expected with a question posted that refers to a program that is not running as expected is to post the minimum amount of source code sufficient to demonstrate the problem that needs to be resolved. This source code should be posted as part of the question itself and not as a link to some resource not on StackOverflow. Screen shots are frowned upon. Any images must be embedded in the posting itself. All of these requirements about posting material in the question itself is to eliminate the possibility of link rot in which links no longer work. Questions and answers tend to last years.

Comment: *A function cannot be accessed when the program is running* it is probably hardly accessible when app is not running :)